# Using git clean filter on windows, script does not make substitution

Tags: bash, git, sed

I'm trying to increment a value within a file when it gets staged.  I'm using clean filter with:

`*.txt filter=increv` in `.gitattributes`

and the following in my `.git/config`

```
[filter "increv"]
  clean = sh 'inc_rev'
```

`inc_rev` has

```bash
#!/bin/sh
STDIN=$(cat)
[[ $STDIN =~ (MyRev_)([0-9]{12}) ]]
i=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}          #group i'd like to keep to put back in
j=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}          #part i need to increment
[[ $j =~ ^0*([^0]+.*$) ]]
k=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}          #trim away the 0's
m=$((k+1))                    #increments
printf -v n "%012d" $m        #repads the 0's into $n
echo STDIN | sed 's|MyRev_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|$i$n|g'
```

And the line I'm trying to increment in *.txt files:

```
TEXT "MyRev_000000000019"
```

My problem is the substitution is not happening and I'm not sure how to debug.
When I run `git status` I can see that my script `inc_rev` is getting called becuase if there's any problem with the script it will return an error in the `git status` message.

**UPDATE1**: shell is bash

**UPDATE2**: here's the result of the following commands:

issuing `git config filter.increv.clean`

yields `bash inc_rev`

issuing `git check-attr -a *.txt`

yields `test.txt: filter: increv`

Comment: You don't do any error checking. If the regex does not match, your variables will be empty.

Comment: For debugging, I would put a `set -x` into your script.

Comment: useful info on [how git works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69832465/11305111)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the filter is running just fine. Clean filters produce the content that will be added to the repo, they don't touch what's in your work tree. Say `git cat-file blob :test.txt` to check what's indexed there.

If your build system's `make`, add a makefile `bump` target that bumps the version number and adds it, otherwise whatever recipe system you're using it'll have some equivalent, use that.

Comment: yep i think this is the case, i checked the repo and the file has the variable incremented... also when i pull there's no change to the local file... which is not what i expected.  any idea why?  regardless, it seems this will not work for what i intended.  any other options besides make?  this repo is just tracking a text file.

Comment: also, `git cat-file blob :test.txt` does show the variable incremented.

Comment: One thing you could do is use a smudge filter for that file instead, that way the increment  happens on checkout.

Comment: smudge also has strange behaviour.  in the end, you're right on, the filter was working (with @markp-fuso correction) but the way it worked was not what i expected.  ultimately my solution was using a precommit hook as described [here](https://superuser.com/a/828137)... in my case i used a script to do the substitution and then with `git add ./text.txt` command at the end.

Answer (score 2):

A few issues with the current script:

- the shebang `#!/bin/sh` implies the script will be run under the `sh` shell; depending on how your system was setup this could be `sh` or a link to `bash`, `dash` or some other shell; suggest using `#!/bin/bash` to insure the script runs under `bash`
- your variables (`$i`, `$n`) cannot be expanded/replaced when the `sed` script is wrapped in single quotes; suggest wrapping the `sed` script in double quotes
- `echo STDIN` is going to print the literal string `STDIN`; assuming you want to print the *contents* of the `STDIN` variable then you'll want to use `echo "$STDIN"`

Pulling all of this into OP's current script

```
$ cat testme
#!/bin/bash
STDIN=$(cat)
[[ $STDIN =~ (MyRev_)([0-9]{12}) ]]
i=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
j=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
[[ $j =~ ^0*([^0]+.*$) ]]
k=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
m=$((k+1))
printf -v n "%012d" $m
# echo "$STDIN" | sed "s|MyRev_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|$i$n|g"
echo "$STDIN" | sed "s|$i$j|$i$n|g"
```

I went ahead and cleaned up the `sed` script to make use of the `$i` and `$j` variables, too.

Taking for a test drive:

```
$ echo 'TEXT "MyRev_000000000019"' | ./testme
TEXT "MyRev_000000000020"
```

Comment: thx! I'm now getting your result with your test, but when I run `cat test.txt | ./tesme` I get `sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression` any thoughts?

Comment: if I place `TEXT "MyRev_000000000019"` into `test.txt` and run `cat test.txt | ./testme` I get  `TEXT "MyRev_000000000020"`; assuming your script is an exact copy of mine then I'd have to guess there's something in your test.txt` that's causing issues ... in which case we'd need to see what's in your `test.txt` ... plus you could enable debugging (add a `set -xv` between the shebang and `STDIN=$(cat)` and run script again) with the objective being to see what's being placed into each variable; alternative to the `set -xv` add `typeset -p STDIN i j k m n` at the end to see what's in each var

Comment: if I go back to this `echo "$STDIN" | sed "s|MyRev_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|$i$n|g"` it now works on the file.  BUT still not getting the substitution to happen when staging the txt file in git

Comment: are you still using `clean = sh 'inc_rev'` or did you change it to `clean = bash 'inc_rev'`? I don't work with `git` but I'm assuming that `sh` is a reference to whatever's in your `/bin/sh` which in turn would override the script's `#!/bin/bash` shebang; try changing to `clean = bash 'inc_rev'` to see if that helps; as for the `sed` change ... may also be related to the `sh` vs `bash` so see if my `sed` works once you switch to `clean = bash 'inc_rev'` ... ?  adding those debug steps (`set -xv` or `typeset -p STDIN i j k m n`) will probably show which vars are not getting set under `sh`

Comment: confirmed bash shell.  i tried updating to `clean=bash inc_rev` and also adding a .sh 
 and then `clean=inc_rev.sh` both seem to call the script with `git status`  its just the substituion doesn't happen when the files are staged.  [here's](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_keyword_expansion) some info on what i'm expecting.  that said, i can see in the terminal that `cat text.txt | ./inc_rev` does make the substitution.